# Rxjs handle error in separate pipeline and merge

Tags: rxjs

I want to split `Observable` into two streams of `Observable` on error

`catch` operator can convert error into valid by returning an observable or propagate error either by `throw`ing or returning `Observable.throw`

`partition` operator only processes valid values, no errors pass through this

what I need is split `Observable` into two `Observable`s and process then differently and merge them as seen in below diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern like this might fit your use case

```js
step1
  .map((data)=>{data:data})
  .catch(()=>Observable.of({error:'error'})
  .flatMap((res)=>{
    //process A and B should return observable
    if(res.data) return processA(res)
    return processB(res)
  })
  .map(res=>{
  //do your merged processing here 
  })
  .subscribe()
```

Comment: it will not work, since after the first `error` `step1` stream will not emit any further values. Another smaller thing is `if(res.data) return processA(res)`

Comment: Observable.of in catch should have converted the error to normal observable item, so it will still emit. Please see this example
https://jsfiddle.net/c8hLezf4/

Comment: You technically did **not** throw in your jsfiddle and catch was not hit - see here: https://jsfiddle.net/c8hLezf4/3/. If you did throw, then the rest of the array would not be emitted as it would be against observable interface.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak @FanCheung I'm doing something similar converting required error into valid value in `catch` and applying `partition`
But i feel it is too brittle solution any way to get new Observable stream from errors directly

Comment: @arturgrzesiak you are right, onResumeNext() might be able to keep the  stream going it but it's not available in rxjs5